# filter, object "course" not found

Tags: r

The data is a survey about courses that students registered this semester.

```
             name       course
1            Bella      HUDK 4050
2            Jay        HUDK 4050
3            Melissa    HUDK 4050
4            Petter     HUDM 5942
5            Yang
```

I want to delete students who take course `HUDK4050` and who didn't answer the questionnaire. "course" is a column name.

```
    HUDK2 = filter(HUDK1, course > 0, course!= "HUDK 4050")
```

then I got this error

> Error in match.arg(method) : object 'course' not found

Answer (score 2):

You may have a separate package loaded that defines filter differently to dplyr. Can you try:

```
HUDK2 <- dplyr::filter(HUDK1, course >0, course!="HUDK 4050")
```